# Class Not found in java web start

Tags: java, jar, java-web-start

I  am using Java web start to launch jar file.

I followed the following tutorials

http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-web-start-jnlp-tutorial-unofficial-guide/

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/web-start/java-web-start-getting-started/

I created java project from my eclipse IDE.

Structure as in my eclipse ide and in folder is as follows,

[image]

I pasted the jar and jnlp files in tomcat/webapps/ROOT folder, the content of ROOT folder as follows,

```
    D:\tomcat7\webapps\ROOT>dir
     Volume in drive D is RECOVERY
     Volume Serial Number is DC2F-E701

     Directory of D:\tomcat7\webapps\ROOT

    18-11-2015  19:23    <DIR>          .
    18-11-2015  19:23    <DIR>          ..
    17-11-2015  16:17               301 .classpath
    17-11-2015  16:17               387 .project
    17-11-2015  16:17    <DIR>          .settings
    23-09-2015  15:19             5,866 asf-logo-wide.gif
    23-09-2015  15:19            17,811 asf-logo.png
    23-09-2015  15:19               713 bg-button.png
    23-09-2015  15:19             1,918 bg-middle.png
    23-09-2015  15:19             1,392 bg-nav-item.png
    23-09-2015  15:19             1,401 bg-nav.png
    23-09-2015  15:19             3,103 bg-upper.png
    23-09-2015  15:19             3,469 build.xml
    17-11-2015  16:48    <DIR>          com
    23-09-2015  15:19            21,630 favicon.ico
    23-09-2015  15:19            12,408 index.jsp
    17-11-2015  16:21             2,957 JNLPExample.jar
    17-11-2015  16:22               612 JNLPExample.jnlp
    17-11-2015  16:20    <DIR>          META-INF
    23-09-2015  15:19             9,195 RELEASE-NOTES.txt
    23-09-2015  15:19             2,376 tomcat-power.gif
    23-09-2015  15:19             5,926 tomcat.css
    23-09-2015  15:19             2,066 tomcat.gif
    23-09-2015  15:19             5,103 tomcat.png
    23-09-2015  15:19            67,787 tomcat.svg
    23-09-2015  15:20    <DIR>          WEB-INF
                  20 File(s)        166,421 bytes
                   6 Dir(s)   2,712,481,792 bytes free

    D:\tomcat7\webapps\ROOT>
```

output of jar -tvf JNLPExample.jar

```
    D:\tomcat7\webapps\ROOT>jar -tvf JNLPExample.jar
       338 Tue Nov 17 16:21:16 IST 2015 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
       500 Tue Nov 17 16:21:16 IST 2015 META-INF/STATHIS.SF
       977 Tue Nov 17 16:21:16 IST 2015 META-INF/STATHIS.DSA
         0 Tue Nov 17 16:20:06 IST 2015 META-INF/
       301 Tue Nov 17 16:17:16 IST 2015 .classpath
       387 Tue Nov 17 16:17:16 IST 2015 .project
         0 Tue Nov 17 16:17:16 IST 2015 .settings/
       598 Tue Nov 17 16:17:18 IST 2015 .settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
```

my .classpath file (of that extracted JNLPExmaple.jar)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <classpath>
        <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
        <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.7"/>
        <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
    </classpath>
```

my .project file  (of that extracted JNLPExmaple.jar)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <projectDescription>
        <name>JNLPExample</name>
        <comment></comment>
        <projects>
        </projects>
        <buildSpec>
            <buildCommand>
                <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
                <arguments>
                </arguments>
            </buildCommand>
        </buildSpec>
        <natures>
            <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
        </natures>
    </projectDescription>
```

I am getting the following error while installing the app. It says

```
"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: main.javacodegeeks.JNLPExample"
```

But it is available in that package.

Following the jnlp file I used,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://localhost:8080/" href="JNLPExample.jnlp">
         <information>
              <title>JNLP Example</title>
              <vendor>Java Code Geeks</vendor>
              <homepage href="http://localhost:8080/" />
              <description>JNLP Testing</description>
         </information>
         <security>
              <all-permissions/>
         </security>
         <resources>
              <j2se version="1.6+" />
              <jar href="JNLPExample.jar" />
         </resources>
         <application-desc main-class="main.javacodegeeks.JNLPExample" />
    </jnlp>
```

Comment: Could anyone assist here?

Comment: 1) Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available at my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0). 2) In cases of CNFE it is necessary to know both the classpath (revealed in the content of the JNLP) as well as the structure of the file system (on the server) that contains those files (showing a listing containing them).  So also add those details as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33755223/edit).

Comment: @AndrewThompson, I updated question with my jnlp file here. Pls guide me what to do in this.

Comment: Where is the data on the file locations on the server?  Going by the JNLP, the `JNLPExample.jar` needs to be in the same directory as launch file.  Note that is also needs to be called `JNLPExample.jar` and not `JNLPexample.jar` or `jnlpexample.jar` (upper/lower case matters).  While we are on the subject of class path, provide a listing of the structure of that Jar.  Note that I have no time for playing '20 questions' at the moment, so when I ask for information, please ensure you provide all of it.  (This is the **2nd time** I've needed to ask you for the directory structure on server.)

Comment: Have you considered following an [official tutorial from Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/index.html)? THere is really no need to rely on arbitrary Internet junk.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, apologies. I updated my question here as you asked.

Comment: *"I updated my question here as you asked."*  Good.  For future reference, it is far more useful to have the information as text rather than screenshots.  This is most easily obtained by copy/pasting from the output window of the IDE (if you can find a way to get it to list required details to the console).  There are a number of reasons for favoring text over images, but the one most relevant to this problem is that from the screenshot of the directory, I cannot tell which `JNLPExamle` is `JNLPExamle.jar` More importantly, it prevents me from checking the file extension for `jar` vs `JAR` ..

Comment: The way to get information from the command line interface (CLI/DOS prompt) is to do a directory listing using `dir`.  Best way to get a Jar content is doing (something like, check docs) `jar -tvf JNLPExamle.jar`.  The way to copy from CLI, right click for the menu, select 'copy', then drag the mouse across the text to be copied & hit the 'enter' key.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, Thanks for the explanation. I updated my question again, hope this is what you asked.

Comment: OK that's the directory structure (and everything seems OK).  What about the output of `jar -tvf JNLPExamle.jar`?

Comment: Yes, I added that too in that question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your jar file there was no package as main/javacodegeeks.There sholud be a class file inside that folder.You can add them and compress a jar again and try then, also you can expose it exe jar so that it will compressed as it is.

Hope it helps..